# Difference Between Class References In Method and Heap Area of JVM

Tags: java, architecture, jvm

The Other day I was looking into JVM architecture, and now I'm really confused. 
Articles on net says JVM assigns memory to only one Instance of Class, and objects could have multiple instance loaded as uses. Now JVM also loads info about class in method area too. 
So what is the difference between two class reference one in Method area and one in Heap.
As method area sounds fine as it stores class level info like static variables and methods but why there is memory for class in Heap..?

Comment: Did they, by any means, spoke about the `class`-field returned by [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())? If so: the `class`-field is a reference to a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html)-instance and this istance (since it is an object) resides on the heap.

Comment: yes Class instance is there on heap but what type of data is stored in this Class instance in Heap and also why do we need that data when we have metadata in method area?

Comment: The source code of OpenJDK is... well... open source. [Why not take a look?](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java)

Comment: yeah got it ...any use cases apart from getClass() or other methods(forName() to create Objects), I mean real life uses of this instance?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: its part of the question !.

Comment: Your question is jumping between entirely different terms. First, you describe *memory for instances of classes*, the next sentence is about “*info about class in method area*”, then, you are suddenly asking a question about “*two class reference* one in Method area and one in Heap”. What do you mean with that term “*class reference*” you never used before? Everything before that was simple and comprehensible “*memory for instances*” and “*info about class*”, two entirely different things, then, you suddenly express a confusion about something called “*class reference*”.